# How is the term "Abstract Data Types" interpreted?

Tags: oop, computer-science

What's the right way to process the phrase "**Abstract Data Types**"? Is it:

```
Abstract-Data Types
```

Or,

```
Abstract Data-Types
```

Comment: It's rather the latter

Comment: Neither - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type

Comment: @EdHeal I don't think OP is asking about how ADT is spelled, but rather how to parse the phrase. Does "Abstract" modify "Data Types" or does "Abstract Data" modify "Types".

Comment: Can you not hold both interpretations in your head at the same time. Then resolve it according to the context?

Comment: The latter is better

Comment: It's the latter. There is no such thing an "abstract data". Data is always concrete.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is a well-explained term.
Precisely, there is no need to write a hyphen among those words.

In some circumstances, there could be the necessity to define conceptual data as ‘`abstract-data`’. But when it comes to terminology in computer science, it’s more general to use without a hyphen which is called ‘`abstract data`’.
(If there should be a hyphen in the phrase, ‘`abstract data-type`’ would be more appropriate than ‘`abstract-data type`’.)

In conclusion, ‘`abstract data type`’ is the most generally used term.